# Configure JFrog artifact repository for Maven project

Tags: maven, jfrog-cli, jfrog-mission-control, jfrog-container-registry

I'm working on some generic template which I need to use Jfrog artifactory for the repository. I have gone through their documents they are specified to use setting.xml (need to add report info) for maven, but I don't want to force down the users to change there settings.xml who are going to use my template.
So i want it should be in my parent pom to access this and use further.

Answer (score 0):

While you *can* define repositories in (parent) POMs, the `settings.xml` often overrides these settings.

If the `settings.xml` has a `<mirror>*</mirror>` entry, everything from the (parent) POM will be useless.

So the standard way to go is to change the `settings.xml`.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, but in my case i don't want to use settings.xml to specify the repo and sanpshot definitions. I can't able to ask everyone who is going to use my parent pom. Is there any alternative fot it.

Comment: You can add the repository to parent POM, but beware, as I said: Many people have mirror configurations in their `settings.xml` and they will override your repository definition in the parent POM.